# Склонение фамилии Кульша

Tags: склонение-фамилий, фамилии

Кульша — ударный "а". Женский вариант этой фамилии не склоняется, а мужской склоняется? По каким правилам такое разделение, насколько оно верно?

Answer (score 1):

Словарь на Грамоте.ру говорит:

> 3.6. Славянские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на -а ударное, склоняются: СКОВОРОДА Григорий, Сковороды Григория (укр. философ); ПОТЕБНЯ
>   Александр, Потебни Александра (укр. и рос. филолог--славист).
>   3.7. Французские фамилии и личные имена, оканчивающиеся на -а ударное, не склоняются: ТАЛЬМА Франсуа, нескл. (франц. актёр); ТОМА Амбруаз,
>   Тома Амбруаза (франц. композитор); ГАМАРРА Пьер, Гамарра Пьера (франц.
>   писатель); ДЮМА Александр, Дюма Александра (франц. писатель).
>   3.8. Некоторые африканские фамилии на -а ударное испытывают колебания в склонении: БАБАНГИДА Ибрагим, Бабангиды Ибрагима (гос. деятель
>   Нигерии); ЯМАРА Семоко [сэ], нескл. (общ. деятель Чада).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/sklon

Если у Вас славянская фамилия, то она склоняется: Николая Кульши, с Николаем Кульшой, к Николаю Кульше.